# jsFiddle document.getElementById inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, jsfiddle

I know jsFiddle displays it's results in an iFrame. I am taking a JS class right now and according to my instructor, "getElementById" is the most used function in all of JS.

So why doesn't "getElementById" work in jsFiddle:

```
document.getElementById("myH1")
```

However...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("H1")
```

Does work!

See my fiddle for the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uM9t4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does, its just your thinking of how replace works is wrong, it does not do an inline change it returns the changed string, if it didnt work you would be getting an

> Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of null

---

```
document.getElementById("myH1").getAttribute("class").replace("bye","NO");
```

should be

```
var change = document.getElementById("myH1").getAttribute("class").replace("bye","NO");
document.getElementById("myH1").setAttribute("class",change);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uM9t4/2/)

Comment: Ok, I guess where I am getting confused is when using Chrome's built in dev tools for debugging JS, I put 'document.getElementsByTagName("H1")' into the console and get back what I expect, however when I put 'document.getElementById("myH1")' it just returns "null". Do you know why?

Comment: @Vippy Because when using the dev tools console you are not operating within the iframe, you are operating in the JSFiddle window. And since the fiddle uses h1 elements you would get those elements returned. You could get a reference to the iframe's document by doing something like `document.getElementById("FramesID").contentDocument` but the way they have it setup you cannot access it due to cross-domain origin policies.

Comment: Ok, this makes perfect sense now. I knew it had something to do with iFrame but wasn't exactly sure till now. Thank you for helping me grow my JS knowledge! =)

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById("myH1")` does work.

I think what you are trying to do is change the attribute of class from having "bye" to having "NO", which doesn't work. You are getting the class and changing it properly, but it is just a string. You have to then reassign it back to the class attribute.

```
document.getElementById("myH1").setAttribute('class', document.getElementById("myH1").getAttribute("class").replace("bye","NO"));
```

Or, stashing the element in a variable:

```
var myH1 = document.getElementById("myH1");
myH1.setAttribute('class', myH1.getAttribute('class').replace('bye', 'NO'));
```

Comment: Thanks @samanime for your help. I also just discovered I could do the same thing using JQuery .addClass() or .removeClass()

Comment: Indeed. And that is generally easier... though it is good to know how to do it with just vanilla JavaScript, since sometimes jQuery is overkill.